# ETL architecture

Tags: java, architecture, etl

I've been asked to make an ETL-style application that transfers information from one data source to another. At the moment, I've decided to use a three-layer architecture but I would like to find out more about the best practices as well as the life cycle described on this wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

Four-layered approach for ETL architecture design

- **Functional layer**: Core functional ETL processing (extract, transform, and load).
- **Operational management layer**: Job-stream definition and management, parameters, scheduling, monitoring, communication and alerting.
- **Audit, balance and control (ABC) layer**: Job-execution statistics, balancing and controls, rejects- and error-handling, codes management.
- **Utility layer**: Common components supporting all other layers.

Real-life ETL cycle

The typical real-life ETL cycle consists of the following execution steps:

1. Cycle initiation
2. Build reference data
3. Extract (from sources)
4. Validate
5. Transform (clean, apply business rules, check for data integrity, create aggregates or disaggregates)
6. Stage (load into staging tables, if used)
7. Audit reports (for example, on compliance with business rules. Also, in case of failure, helps to diagnose/repair)
8. Publish (to target tables)
9. Archive
10. Clean up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what your situation is or what your requirements are, but you're likely over thinking the problem.

The name alone is "the" architecture:

- Extract
- Transform
- Load

Exporting a DB table to a CSV can be considered "ET" while loading the CSV is the "L". Most ETL problems are simply not complicated.

Beyond that, you should grab any of the 1 or 2 million ETL and ESB packages already available in Java, free and commercial, libraries and full boat processing systems, and simply adopt one of them that you like best.

Get a white board, string some bubbles together with lines and turn that in to code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, "What's the best practice?" the answer depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

To simplify let's assume you are doing one of the following:

1. You are building a data warehouse that will restructure the data in some way
2. You are moving data from point A to point B, but you are not restructuring the data

When I use the word "restructuring", I mean changing the grain or lowest level of detail of a table.

For 1.  The ten steps outlined in your question is generally followed.  General best practices:

- As much transformation logic as possible is pushed onto database resources, not ETL software (ETL software is generally slower)
- Validate, Transform, and Audit steps are used to employ whatever Master Data Management (MDM) standards your organization uses

For 2.  This is much more straightforward so either method outlined in your question can be used.